# Flask-WTF CSRF token is missing

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

Following the documentation of flask-wtf (v. 0.14.2, python 3.4.6) [here](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) I get a `CSRF token is missing` 400 error when reacting on a `onchange` event from a simple radio button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Send the status of the radio buttons using AJAX
function radio_changed(){
  var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
            }
        }
    });
    var radioValue = $("input[class=radios]:checked").val();
   //alert(radioValue);
   $.ajax({
                    url: '/_radio_update',
                    data: {value:radioValue},
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                    }
            });
}
</script>
```

then later

```
<form method=post action="">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
...
```

on the Flask side:

```
...
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'shhhhhhh!'
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)

@app.route('/_radio_update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def _radio_update(radiostatus):
    print(radiostatus)
...
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Does the browser actually send the token? Check the network tab in your dev tools. If it doesn't, is it because `this.crossDomain` is true?

Comment: Under network --> headers --> request headers I see only a session cookie, no tokens. I tried also with `crossDomain:false` with same results. Also tried `jsonp` as described in this [tutorial](https://d-mueller.de/blog/cross-domain-ajax-guide/) also didn't help. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If the server says it can't see the CSRF token, it's either not there, or there is a bug in the server. We just narrowed it down to the token not there and specifically the browser not sending it. Next you can trace the JavaScript line by line to see what doesn't go as planned.

Comment: ok, but just to make sure again what I should expect to see in case of correct behavior while debugging JS: if the token is sent, it will appear in the request header section, right? How will it look like?

Comment: You'll have a `X-CSRFToken` header with some random value.

Comment: yes. I see the token: it is given to the client, and client gives it back. So the problem must be server side.

Comment: It might also be something between the client and the server like a reverse-proxy that strips it away. Try picking it part by part until you find out where the token is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is a difference between `Forms` imported from `wtforms` and the one imported from `flask.ext.wtf` which according to the note at the end of the [documentation](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12/csrf.html?highlight=csrf) causes the problem.

After dealing with the the deprecation notice, finally I changed the line:

```
from wtforms import Form, RadioField, SubmitField, validators
class InputForm(Form):
...
```

to

```
from wtforms import RadioField, SubmitField, validators
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
class InputForm(FlaskForm):
...
```

this solved the problem for me.